# `return` in main environment

Tags: ruby, return, program-entry-point

When I run the following in the main environment in irb or pry,

```rb
return "foo"
```

I get:

```
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

which is expected. But when I write this code in a separate file `foo.rb`, and do:

```
$ ruby foo.rb
```

in the console, it terminates without any error message.

What is happening in the latter case?

I thought a raised error might be silently disposed with, and tried the following in a separate file:

```rb
begin
  return "foo"
rescue Exception => e
  p e
end
```

and executed it from the console, but this also resulted in no error.

When I put the code in an environment such as a module, it returns the error:

```rb
module A
  return "foo" # >> Invalid return in class/module body
end
```

Comment: In both cases, from file and from `irb`, the `self` context is `main`. This is a peculiar quirk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top-level return was added as a feature in ruby 2.4.0: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4840

It was never mentioned in the [release announcement](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/), but you can see it listed under the "language changes" in the more detailed [news post](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/NEWS).

If you run a file which contains `return "foo"` in ruby version `< 2.4.0`, you will indeed see an error like:

```
foo.rb:1:in `<main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
```

The intended use case (as you can see from the above link) was for "cancelling a `require`" - e.g. if the file is platform-specific, such as:

```
require "test/unit"

return unless /mswin|cygwin|mingw|bccwin/

# ...
```

There was much discussion and debate over proposed syntax and behaviour; but the chosen implementation can perhaps be best understood by reading the implementation's [test cases](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1043/files#diff-4216bbf6387c50d56b418c67768dcccb):

```
def test_return_toplevel
  feature4840 = '[ruby-core:36785] [Feature #4840]'
  code = <<~'CODE'
  return; raise
  begin return; rescue SystemExit; exit false; end
  begin return; ensure exit false; end
  begin ensure return; end
  begin raise; ensure; return; end
  begin raise; rescue; return; end
  return false; raise
  return 1; raise
  CODE
  all_assertions(feature4840) do |a|
    code.each_line do |s|
      s.chomp!
      a.for(s) {assert_ruby_status([], s)}
    end
  end
end
```

Since writing `return` inside a REPL like `pry` is not at the "top level", this results in a `LocalJumpError` instead of the above special behaviour for "top-level `return`".